# Array declaration is not clear

Tags: vhdl

With code:

```
type x_array is array(1 to 2 * con'high - 2) of signed (7 downto 0);
```

What is the work of con'high?

In the program `con` is an array defined as:

```
generic(
  con : const_array := ("00110011", "00110011", "00110011", "00110011"));
  ...
```

and `const_array` is an unconstrained array of 8 bits.

Please explain what is `2 * con'high - 2`?

Comment: you should add more detail to your question, how can we know what con'high might mean

Comment: package --- is
type const_array is array(positive array <>) of signed(7 downto ));
end package;

Answer (score 2):

The `con'high` is a reference to the `high` attribute of the `con` array, and returns the highest (greatest) index value for the `con` array range.

So for `x_array` the `2 * con'high - 2` is used as part of the index range for ´x_array´ in order to define the `x_array` range based on `con`.

The actual value of `con'high` depends on the declaration of `const_array`, or rather the type used for the range of `const_array`.  So for various declarations of `const_array`:

```
type const_array is array(positive range <>) of signed(7 downto 0);
-- Range is 1 to 4, and con'high = 4

type const_array is array(natural range <>) of signed(7 downto 0);
-- Range is 0 to 3, and con'high = 3

type const_array is array(integer range <>) of signed(7 downto 0);
-- Range is integer'low to integer'low + 3, and con'high = integer'low + 3, 
-- e.g. -2147483645 for 32-bit integer
```

Or more odd like:

```
subtype const_array_range is natural range 17 downto 14;
type const_array is array(const_array_range) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- Range is 17 to 14, and con'high = 17
```

Or it could even be a value in an enumerated type with declarations like:

```
type const_array_range is (ALFA, BRAVO, CHARLIE, DELTA, ECHO);
type const_array is array(const_array_range range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
-- Range is ALFA to DELTA, and con'high = DELTA
```

The last will of course result in error when using `con'high` in `2 * con'high - 2`, but again, the value depends on the declaration of `const_array`.